# Product of two sequences of random variables converging in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

The following is an exercise in Prof Tao's lecture notes on probability theory.

We assume that a sequence of random variables $\xi_n \rightarrow \xi$ in distribution and also $\nu_n \rightarrow \nu$ in distribution as well.

(i) If $\nu$ equals a constant almost surely, then prove that the product $\xi_n \nu_n$ converges to $\xi \nu$ in distribution.

(ii) Find a counterexample to (i) in the case $\nu$ does not equal a constant a.s.

Any help, hints will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(i) We have to show that $\xi_n(\nu_n-\nu)$ goes to $0$ in probability. Take $\varepsilon\gt 0$; then for each positive $R$, 
$$\mu\{|\xi_n(\nu_n-\nu)|\gt\varepsilon\}\leqslant \mu\{|\xi_n|\geqslant R\}+\mu\{|\nu_n-\nu|\geqslant \varepsilon/R\}.$$
We then have by portmanteau theorem that for each $R$, 
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\mu\{|\xi_n(\nu_n-\nu)|\gt\varepsilon\}\leqslant\mu\{|\xi|\geqslant R\},$$
and we conclude, as $R$ was arbitrary.

(ii) Take $\xi_n$ and $\nu_n$ discrete random variable with disjoint support and which converge to a continuous distribution (for example, we can use Riemann sums).

Comment: I am sorry, but how do you finish the argument of (i)?

Comment: The sequence $(\{|\xi|\geqslant N\})_{N\geqslant 1}$ is non-increasing, and $\bigcap_N\{|\xi|\geqslant N\}=\emptyset$.

Comment: Yes, but we want to $ \xi_n \nu_n$ converges to $\xi \nu$ in distribution.

Comment: Instead, you showed that $\xi_n (\nu_n - \nu) $ converges to zero in probability

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that there can't be any examples for (ii) with any type of convergence:

- $v_n$ does not converge to a constant almost surely by task description
- if $v_n$ was to converge in probability to a constant, then, by [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem), the product $\xi_n v_n$ also converged in distribution
- if $v_n$ was to converge in distribution to a constant, then it also [converged in probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution_to_a_constant_implies_convergence_in_probability). Continue with the second point from here.